# makefile - How to make .NOTPARALLEL propagate into submakes

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Do I have to put `.NOTPARALLEL` in every makefile?

I'd like to put it in a top-level one and then propagate it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add:

```
MAKEFLAGS += -j1
```

to your top-level makefile and it should disable parallel builds in the sub-makes (note I didn't test this but it *should* work :)).